# Programmatically pushing apk file to an Android device

Tags: android

I am working with some Android wearables that do not support downloads from Playstore.

If we happen to ship these devices, we install our Android application prior to shipping. This works great.

I am looking at ways to install our application on those wearables that the customers purchased directly.

In our case, the wearable is typically paired with another Android device (typically a phone). My thought is to write an application for the phone that may communicate with the wearable either via Bluetooth or on adb port (if possible).

1. If I could communicate via adb TCP port, I can install the apk from the mobile phone onto the wearable. Are there any programmatic interfaces available that an Android application can consume?
2. Otherwise, is there any other way to connect via Bluetooth and push the .apk?

There are many links on automating install via adb from the desktop. However, in my case, the install has to happen from the mobile phone and not from the desktop. Regards.

Comment: AFAIK, In general, installing apps on Android device programatically requires super-user privileges, and those are impossible to [legally] acquire.

Comment: Thanks. I should have been more clear. After I transfer the .apk file, I just need some way to fire up the appropriate intent to install the .apk. In this case, I don't need any superuser privilege. The user may choose to install or ignore.

Answer (score 1):

Package the wearable inside a companion application for the phone (even an empty one with no launcher icon would do the job), and they should get installed to any paired wearable device when the app is installed on the phone.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What do you mean by package the wearable? How would it automatically get installed on the paired device?

Comment: The standard method of installing a wearable app is to package it as a inside of a handheld application. Read [https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating.html) for more information, but to summarise:

When you're ready to publish your app to users, you embed the wearable app inside of the handheld app. When a user installs the handheld app from Google Play, a connected wearable automatically receives the wearable app.